# jQuery Parent Child Element Click Event

Tags: jquery, input, click, parent-child, stoppropagation

My HTML looks something like this (unfortunately it cannot change because it is being rendered with the CMS I am using):

```
<li>
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox">
<label for="cb1">
<div>Some Other Content</div>
<div class="pledge">Click to Pledge</div>
</label>
</li>
```

The jQuery.

```
$("div.pledge").click(function() {

  var checkboxlabel = $(this).parent("label");

  $("input[for=checkboxlabel]").attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));

});
```

Using this code will toggle the checkbox if I click anywhere inside the label.  What I need is for the action to only take place when I click the `<div class="pledge">` element.  I suspect that .stopPropagation(); will help me here but I have not been able to get it to work properly.

Here is another shot that seems to be accomplishing the same think:

```
$("div.pledge").click(function() {

  $("input[for=' + this.parent("label").attr("id") + ']").attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));

});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't put an id on the checkbox and then point the label to that id with the for attribute? And ditch the jquery.

Comment: I don't see how that code does anything, let alone the wrong thing. Is the selector `"input[for=checkboxlabel]"` supposed to be somehow referencing the variable `checkboxlabel` created on the line before? Because as it stands it doesn't reference anything in the html you've shown. Also, is `$checkbox` defined somewhere?

Comment: I thought checkboxlabel was referencing the label which I got here `$(this).parent("label");`.  The label is a parent of the `<div class="pledge">` element

Comment: The variable `checkboxlabel` would be a jQuery object with one element that is the label element, but with your current html that label isn't associated with an input and in any case using the name of the variable within a string doesn't reference the variable at all. In a general sense you can concatenate a variable onto a string: `"string literal " + someVariable` but that doesn't make sense unless `someVariable` is a string too, or can be converted to one. Your `checkboxlabel` doesn't have a meaningful string representation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading between the lines, it seems to me that the following will achieve your desired result without any JS:

```
<li>
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox">
<div>
<div>Some Other Content</div>
<label for="cb1">Click to Pledge</label>
</div>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/VqmBb/

This displays "Some Other Content" and "Click to Pledge" next to the checkbox, but as you can see with my demo only the "Click to Pledge" part checks/unchecks the box when clicked.

I've swapped your label and the "pledge" div around, and made use of the label's `for` attribute to associate it with the checkbox so that it will automatically check/uncheck it. (Though now the outer div doesn't actually do anything and could be removed unless you need it for styling.)

Regarding your JS, the following line has some problems:

```
$("input[for=checkboxlabel]").attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
```

First, your selector `"input[for=checkboxlabel]"` seems to be trying to use the `checkboxlabel` variable declared on the line before, but what you've actually done is just include a string that happens to include the text "checkboxlabel". So that won't select any elements in your html because you have no "input" element with a "for" attribute equal to the string "checkboxlabel". Also you've got a variable `$checkbox` that isn't defined anywhere.

**UPDATE:** OK, the following should work for your updated html (it worked for me). The problem with your existing JS code, apart from the fact that you are trying to use a variable, `$checkbox`, that isn't declared, is that you are trying to bind your click handler to the "pledge" div which means you haven't done anything to handle clicks on other parts of the label. Given that you specifically want to stop clicks on other parts of the label I'd suggest that you attach the `.click()` handler to the *label* - clicks on the label's children will bubble up to the label's click handler, so then you can test whether the element that was clicked was the one with class "pledge". If not return `false` to cancel the default behaviour for a label click, but if it *is* the "pledge" element do nothing and let the default happen:

```
$("div.pledge").parent("label").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("pledge"))
        return false;
});
```

(Note I'm selecting the parent of "div.pledge" rather than just saying `$("label").click()` so that this processing doesn't get attached to *all* labels.)

If you don't like that I think mgibsonbr's answer is a nice alternative.

Comment: I cannot change the html structure.  I am using a CMS that renders the html here the way I have it.  The `id` and `for` are present.

Comment: Well `id` and `for` are present _now_, but they weren't in your original question. I've got to go now, but I'll update my answer once I get back (unless somebody else has already done it by then).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, when you say "you can't change the HTML", you mean only the HTML that is **generated** by the server, right? But can you change it in the client side, using JavaScript?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('label[for="cb1"]').removeAttr("for");
    $("div.pledge").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().prev().attr("checked", function(index,oldValue) {
            return !oldValue;
        });
    });
});
```

This way the label won't have a `for` anymore, and the div click is handled manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, both HTML and JavaScript are invalid.
`<label>` is an `inline` element which can't have `block` elements inside such as `<div>`.
Then, your JS code is missing some `;` (I see you added them). Also, this makes no sense:

```
$("input[for=checkboxlabel]").attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'))
```

This should work. Notice the new html tags and the proper jQuery code:

**html:**

```
<li>
    <label>Something that describes this checkbox</label>
    <input id="check" type="checkbox">
    <p>Some Other Content</p>
    <a href="#" id="pledge">Click to Pledge</a>
</li>
```

**jQ:**

```
$('#pledge').click(function()}{ $('#check').prop('checked', true); });
```

Comment: I understand that this HTML is not the best but unfortunately I have to work with it.  Adding ; did nothing for me here.  Do you have a better alternative for toggling a checkbox on click?

Comment: See edit. And again, that html is NOT valid. Why can't you change it?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going about this the right way - you need to specify the 'for' attribute in your label and set it to the id of the checkbox you're assigning it to like so:

```
<label for="checkbox_id">Label-text</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" />
```

This will check/uncheck the checkbox when you click the label. All the points made by @elclanrs above hold too, the html and js are invalid.

Comment: Yes...getting the code to work when I click on the label is not a problem.  There are many of these elements on the page with many ids that are always being updated so this code needs to be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Move checkbox inside the label element. You don't need any js and even id or for attribute is not required for `input` and `label` element. Try this.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div>Some Other Content</div>
    <div class="pledge">Click to Pledge</div>
</label>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/FcmMV/1/)**